# Interconnect desktop application and android application with one cloud db possible?

Tags: c#, android, database, azure-cloud-services

Me and my team are developing an android application that needs to be connected into a desktop application via cloud db. Is it possible? And what cloud db should we use? Any other additional information would be much appreciated.
Android App - Will be developed using Android Studio(Java)
Desktop Application - Visual Studio(C#)

Answer (score 0):

You can use php and mysql also :) and then make api's . To interconnect Desktop and Android application